# Mozilla SpiderMonkey AST full structure

Tags: abstract-syntax-tree, spidermonkey, uglifyjs

Where can I find the **full** structure of Mozilla SpiderMonkey abstract syntax tree?

Just like this one for UglifyJS: http://lisperator.net/uglifyjs/ast

Answer (score 4):

[The ESTree Spec](https://github.com/estree/estree) is the **official document** for the AST structures generated by the SpiderMonkey/Firefox Parser API.

Answer (score -2):

I thinks the best way to find documentation is here : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/SpiderMonkey

Comment: Been there. Obviously.